# Remove/add class after ALL input checkboxes are unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a long list of input checkboxes generated by PHP, and I'm needing to (1) enable and add/remove a class when **at least one box is checked**, and (2) I'm needing to disable and add/remove a class when **none of the boxes are checked**. So far, I'm able to add/remove the class once a box is checked, but I can't figure out how to do the second part.

Notes: I'm brand new to javascript, so please be kind. Also, the HTML portion cannot change any, due to PHP quirks and other elements on the page that are unrelated.

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <input type='checkbox' name='uuid[]' value=1 id=1 onclick="terms_changed(this)"/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='uuid[]' value=2 id=2 onclick="terms_changed(this)"/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='uuid[]' value=3 id=3 onclick="terms_changed(this)"/>
        // plus unlimited others, you get the idea //
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="button grey-btn" type="submit" id="submit_button" disabled>Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function terms_changed(termsCheckBox){
       document.getElementById("submit_button").disabled = !termsCheckBox.parentElement.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
       document.getElementById("submit_button").classList.remove("grey-btn");
       document.getElementById("submit_button").classList.add("green-btn");
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the class you can do something like below. I am not sure which class to add at which scenario, you can change the code according to your need, but you can just check if the button is disabled then add a class and remove one or do other, as you are already enabling or disabling the button, yo u can use that to add or remove class.

```js
function terms_changed(termsCheckBox){
       document.getElementById("submit_button").disabled = !termsCheckBox.parentElement.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
       if(document.getElementById("submit_button").disabled) {
         document.getElementById("submit_button").classList.remove("grey-btn");
         document.getElementById("submit_button").classList.add("green-btn");
       } else {
       document.getElementById("submit_button").classList.add("grey-btn");
         document.getElementById("submit_button").classList.remove("green-btn");
         }
   }
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <input type='checkbox' name='uuid[]' value=1 id=1 onclick="terms_changed(this)"/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='uuid[]' value=2 id=2 onclick="terms_changed(this)"/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='uuid[]' value=3 id=3 onclick="terms_changed(this)"/>
        // plus unlimited others, you get the idea //
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="button grey-btn" type="submit" id="submit_button" disabled>Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an action after all inputs are unchecked, you can use `document.querySelector` that selects only checked items and get that information

Here's an example:

```js
  function isNoneChecked() {
    const checkedCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    const noneChecked = checkedCheckbox.length === 0;
    return noneChecked;
    }
```

You can simply add this function to your code, then after every input change perform some kind of logic based on this function result:

```js
function terms_changed(termsCheckBox){
       document.getElementById("submit_button").disabled = !termsCheckBox.parentElement.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
       document.getElementById("submit_button").classList.remove("grey-btn");
       document.getElementById("submit_button").classList.add("green-btn");
       
       if (isNoneChecked) {
        // perform logic here
       }  
   }
```

You can read more about `querySelectorAll` in the [MDN docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)